# ASE: Shape mismatch when using FrechetCellFilter filter

Tags: molecular-dynamics, atomic-simulation-environment

I want to use a `FrechetCellFilter` into a MD simulation with ASE to make sure both the atomic forces and unit cell are simultaneously minimised.

I encounter a `shape mismatch` error:
`ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (11,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (8,3)`

I perform first a `QuasiNewton` optimisation which goes through correctly and then a `NPT` relaxation, where the code complains about the filter( `len(ecf)=11` ) being broadcasted to the atoms (`len(atoms)=8`).

Why is the `FrechetCellFilter` working for the optimization and not for the NPT run? Please find below the xyz input file, the python script and the output produced.

Cheers

```
"""Demonstrate use of FrechetCellFilter in molecular dynamics exemple."""

import ase
import numpy as np
from ase.md.npt import NPT
from asap3 import Atoms, units
from xtb.ase.calculator import XTB
from ase.io.trajectory import Trajectory
from ase.filters import FrechetCellFilter
from ase.optimize import QuasiNewton

input_file = 'H2_box.xyz'
cell_size = 2

calculator = XTB(method="GFN1-xTB")

atoms = ase.io.read(input_file)
atoms.rattle(stdev=0.01)
atoms.set_cell(np.array([cell_size, cell_size, cell_size]))
atoms.set_pbc(True)
atoms.center(vacuum=1)
atoms.set_calculator(calculator)

ecf = FrechetCellFilter(atoms)

print('len(atoms)) :', len(atoms))
print('len(ecf))   :', len(ecf))

qn = QuasiNewton(ecf)
traj = Trajectory('full.traj', 'w', atoms)
qn.attach(traj, interval=10)
qn.run(fmax=0.5)

print('len(atoms)) :', len(atoms))
print('len(ecf))   :', len(ecf))


print('---- NPT begins ----')
dyn = NPT(
    ecf,
    timestep=0.1 * units.fs,
    temperature_K=300,
    externalstress=0.000101325 * units.GPa,
    trajectory=traj,
    logfile='NPT.log'
    )

dyn.attach(traj.write, interval=10)
dyn.run(50)
```

Output:

```
len(atoms)) : 8
len(ecf))   : 11
                Step[ FC]     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGSLineSearch:    0[  0] 09:39:12     -108.889007        6.1586
BFGSLineSearch:    1[  2] 09:39:13     -109.473179        1.1762
BFGSLineSearch:    2[  3] 09:39:13     -109.623021        2.2571
BFGSLineSearch:    3[  5] 09:39:13     -110.469132        2.7407
BFGSLineSearch:    4[  7] 09:39:14     -110.635861        2.8123
BFGSLineSearch:    5[  8] 09:39:14     -110.798278        1.1939
BFGSLineSearch:    6[ 10] 09:39:15     -110.852617        1.2630
BFGSLineSearch:    7[ 12] 09:39:15     -110.907418        1.1981
BFGSLineSearch:    8[ 13] 09:39:16     -110.980643        1.0792
BFGSLineSearch:    9[ 14] 09:39:16     -111.035826        0.1971
len(atoms)) : 8
len(ecf))   : 11
---- NPT begins ----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcodigennaro/WORK/TME/PGEL/ASE_tutorials/FrechetCellFilter.py", line 40, in <module>
    dyn = NPT(
          ^^^^
  File "/Users/marcodigennaro/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/md/npt.py", line 149, in __init__
    MolecularDynamics.__init__(self, atoms, timestep, trajectory,
  File "/Users/marcodigennaro/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/md/md.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.atoms.set_momenta(np.zeros([len(self.atoms), 3]))
  File "/Users/marcodigennaro/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/filters.py", line 94, in set_momenta
    mom[self.index] = momenta
    ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (11,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (8,3)
```

Input file: H2_box.xyz

```
           8
  Built with Packmol
  H            0.013589       -0.001149        1.023230
  H            0.000832        0.011254        0.323456
  H            0.051896        1.974564        0.714629
  H            0.370690        1.998602        0.091899
  H            1.944549        1.995178        2.000676
  H            1.963944        2.001188        1.300971
  H            1.933873        0.445614        0.043857
  H            1.974646        0.077936        0.638122
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your NPT object expects a plain `Atoms` object, and not the `Filter` object that you get when doing `ecf = FrechetCellFilter(atoms)`.

`ecf.atoms` will yield the optimized Atoms object without filter, that should work.

Also note that your external stress is 1 eV/AA**3 = 160 GPa.

Edit: Note that none of the `NPT` classes in ASE implements a "proper" NPT sampling. Just as a word of caution.

Comment: Thank you @flonko. This solves the mismatch issue, but the volume and stress are not changing as I'd expect.

Comment: In the new version of the question, I show how neither NVT nor NPT change volume or pressure. Do you know why?

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro please ask a new question. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Nike Dattani, fine by me. I think we could also modify the title otherwise it's misleading. How about "shape mismatch in ASE filter"?

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro great idea! You can go ahead with that title change!